# Multiple Flickity slideshows and adding one dynamically

Tags: javascript, flickity

I have a grid of items on a page on my site. Every now and again a grid item outputs a wrapper with a number of children in it.  Each of these wrappers I have set as a Flickity slider with their children being the slides.

I've initialised it by doing the following:

```
import Flickity from 'flickity'

export let cVWrapperFlkty

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.c-v-wrapper').forEach(cvw => {
        cVWrapperFlkty = new Flickity( cvw, {
            prevNextButtons: false,
            pageDots: false,
            contain: true
        });
    })
})
```

This all works fine.  The next part is where it breaks down.  Above the grid I have pagination links.  When clicked, my page does a request for a json file which replaces the current grid of items with the new set which has been templated in via Handlebars JS.

The issue is that Flickity has now not been set up on the new `.c-v-wrapper` elements in the grid.

How could I adjust the code above so that any new `.c-v-wrapper` elements added automatically get initialised?

After the content of the grid gets replaced I did try adding the following but it doesn;t seem to do anything. I am assuming that is because the cVWrapper variable still refers back to the previous instances of Flickity that no longer exist in the DOM? Does that sound right?

```
cVWrapperFlkty.reloadCells()
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with the `MutationObserver`, which is designed to watch for changes in the DOM tree.

Here's an example of how it could work for you:

```js
// observe-added-node.js


// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
export default function observeAddedNode(classSelector, callback) {
  // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
  const observer = new MutationObserver(function onAddedNode(mutationsList, observer) {
    mutationsList.forEach(mutation => {
      if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
        mutation.addedNodes.forEach(node => {
          if (node.classList && node.classList.contains(classSelector)) {
            callback(node)

            // observer.disconnect() if you don't need to watch for new changes
          }
        })
      }
    })
  })

  // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
  observer.observe(document.querySelector('body'), { childList: true })
}

// ...

// flickity-grid.js

import Flickity from 'flickity'
import observeAddedNode from './observe-added-node'

observeAddedNode('c-v-wrapper', (node) => {
  new Flickity(node, { /* options... * / })
})
```

Here are some good resources to learn more about `MutationObserver`:

- https://codeburst.io/observe-changes-in-dom-using-mutationobserver-9c2705222751
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: Ah interesting. I will take a deeper look into this tonight.  Thanks.  One question.  If I set up a number of Flickity instances and assign them to a variable. When I need to destroy one, how do I know which instance is being referred to when I call it? I get confused with stuff like this and need to fix my understanding!

Comment: MutationObserver also supports observing removedNodes. You can iterate removedNodes and use Flickity.data to access the flickity instance. No need to keep them in a shared variable. https://flickity.metafizzy.co/api.html#flickity-data